# Angular can't find namespace jasmine

Tags: angular, jasmine, angular-cli, typescript-typings

I'm working on an angular project that was generated using the angular cli version 6.0.3. In the past few days, running it, I get the following error:

> ERROR in node_modules/@angular/core/testing/src/testing_internal.d.ts(7,47): error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'jasmine'.

Here are some important files:

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

tsconfig.spec.json:

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/spec",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "types": [
      "jasmine",
      "node"
    ]
  },
  "files": [
    "test.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "**/*.spec.ts",
    "**/*.d.ts",
    "polyfills.ts"
  ]
}
```

tsconfig.app.json

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
    "module": "es2015",
    "types": []
  },
  "exclude": [
    "src/test.ts",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}
```

package.json

```
{
    "name": "xtreme-admin-angular",
    "version": "0.0.0",
    "scripts": {
        "ng": "ng",
        "start": "ng serve",
        "build": "ng build",
        "test": "ng test",
        "lint": "ng lint",
        "e2e": "ng e2e",
        "clean": "npm cache verify"
    },
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
        "@agm/core": "^1.0.0-beta.3",
        "@angular/animations": "^6.0.2",
        "@angular/common": "^6.0.2",
        "@angular/compiler": "^6.0.2",
        "@angular/core": "^6.0.2",
        "@angular/forms": "^6.0.2",
        "@angular/http": "^6.0.2",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.0.2",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.0.2",
        "@angular/router": "^6.0.2",
        "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^2.0.0",
        "@swimlane/ngx-charts": "^7.0.1",
        "@swimlane/ngx-datatable": "^13.0.0",
        "angular-calendar": "^0.25.2",
        "angular-datatables": "^6.0.0",
        "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
        "c3": "^0.4.23",
        "chart.js": "^2.7.1",
        "chartist": "^0.11.0",
        "core-js": "^2.5.4",
        "d3": "^4.8.0",
        "datatables.net": "^1.10.16",
        "datatables.net-dt": "^1.10.16",
        "jquery": "^3.4.1",
        "jwt-decode": "^2.2.0",
        "ng-chartist": "^1.1.1",
        "ng2-charts": "^1.6.0",
        "ng2-dragula": "^1.5.0",
        "ng2-file-upload": "^1.3.0",
        "ng2-smart-table": "1.2.2",
        "ngx-perfect-scrollbar": "6.1.0",
        "ngx-quill": "^3.1.0",
        "ngx-toastr": "^8.7.3",
        "pace-js": "^1.0.2",
        "rxjs": "^6.0.0",
        "rxjs-compat": "^6.2.0",
        "sweetalert2": "8.14.0",
        "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.10.0",
        "@angular/cli": "~6.0.3",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.0.2",
        "@angular/language-service": "^6.0.2",
        "@types/c3": "^0.6.0",
        "@types/chartist": "^0.9.37",
        "@types/datatables.net": "^1.10.10",
        "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.6",
        "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
        "@types/jquery": "^3.2.5",
        "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
        "codelyzer": "~4.2.1",
        "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
        "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
        "karma": "~1.7.1",
        "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
        "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~1.4.2",
        "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.1",
        "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
        "node-sass": "^4.13.1",
        "protractor": "~5.3.0",
        "ts-node": "~5.0.1",
        "tslint": "~5.9.1",
        "typescript": "~2.7.2"
    }
}
```

What could the issue be?

Comment: have you tried reinstalling the package ?

Comment: @micronyks the jasmine package?